# SQL Join Returns Duplicate Results

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I'm trying to return a concatenated list of all customer prompts assigned to each customer, with only one row returned for each customer key (CUS_PK).  The following query gives me the information I'm looking for, but when more than one prompt is assigned to a single customer I'm getting duplicate rows, with each row being identical except that the prompt keys are being returned in all possible combinations, with one row per combination.  I know this is because I'm using joins, but I don't know enough about SQL to come up with another way to do this.

Here's the query I'm using:

```
select CUS1.CUS_PK,
CLP1.CLP_PRM_FK || CASE WHEN CLP2.CLP_PRM_FK <> '' THEN ', ' ELSE '' END ||
CLP2.CLP_PRM_FK || CASE WHEN CLP3.CLP_PRM_FK <> '' THEN ', ' ELSE '' END ||
CLP3.CLP_PRM_FK || CASE WHEN CLP4.CLP_PRM_FK <> '' THEN ', ' ELSE '' END ||
CLP4.CLP_PRM_FK AS 'AP'

FROM ecrs.Customers CUS1

LEFT OUTER JOIN ecrs.CustomerLinkPOSPrompts CLP1 ON (CLP1.CLP_CUS_FK = CUS1.CUS_PK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecrs.CustomerLinkPOSPrompts CLP2 ON (CLP2.CLP_CUS_FK = CUS1.CUS_PK AND CLP2.CLP_PRM_FK<>CLP1.CLP_PRM_FK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecrs.CustomerLinkPOSPrompts CLP3 ON (CLP3.CLP_CUS_FK = CUS1.CUS_PK AND CLP3.CLP_PRM_FK<>CLP2.CLP_PRM_FK AND CLP3.CLP_PRM_FK<>CLP1.CLP_PRM_FK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecrs.CustomerLinkPOSPrompts CLP4 ON (CLP4.CLP_CUS_FK = CUS1.CUS_PK AND CLP4.CLP_PRM_FK<>CLP3.CLP_PRM_FK AND CLP4.CLP_PRM_FK<>CLP2.CLP_PRM_FK AND CLP4.CLP_PRM_FK<>CLP1.CLP_PRM_FK)

ORDER BY CUS1.CUS_PK
```

GROUP BY didn't seem to have any effect.

The duplicate rows look like this, going from 0-3 prompt results:

```
CUS_PK  AP
-----   -----
35331   
35274   40
35342   37, 65
35342   65, 37  
35344   37, 53, 65
35344   53, 65, 37
35344   37, 65, 53
35344   53, 37, 65
35344   65, 53, 37
35344   65, 37, 53
```

Also, how might I specify the order in which the prompts are returned?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Comment: ..just to clarify, you want to return distinct CUS_PK and AP but if the AP contains values (which you concatenated) which are the same (even though in a different order) than you want to exclude that row ?

Comment: Milan: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to join them in a specific order (e.g. using '<=' instead of '<>'):

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecrs.CustomerLinkPOSPrompts CLP1 ON (CLP1.CLP_CUS_FK = CUS1.CUS_PK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecrs.CustomerLinkPOSPrompts CLP2 ON (CLP2.CLP_CUS_FK = CUS1.CUS_PK AND CLP2.CLP_PRM_FK <= CLP1.CLP_PRM_FK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecrs.CustomerLinkPOSPrompts CLP3 ON (CLP3.CLP_CUS_FK = CUS1.CUS_PK AND CLP3.CLP_PRM_FK <= CLP2.CLP_PRM_FK AND CLP3.CLP_PRM_FK <= CLP1.CLP_PRM_FK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecrs.CustomerLinkPOSPrompts CLP4 ON (CLP4.CLP_CUS_FK = CUS1.CUS_PK AND CLP4.CLP_PRM_FK <= CLP3.CLP_PRM_FK AND CLP4.CLP_PRM_FK <= CLP2.CLP_PRM_FK AND CLP4.CLP_PRM_FK <= CLP1.CLP_PRM_FK)
```

Comment: That solves the duplicate row problem, but now I'm getting duplicate results in the concatenated field.  For example, with one match I'm getting "44,44,44,44" instead of just "44" like I was before.  Any ideas?  I appreciate your help.

Comment: the change the <= into <

Comment: Now I seem to be getting duplicate rows again, but each successive row loses one result.  So I may get three rows for CUS_PK=35344, but they look like "65,53,37 / 53,37 / 37".

Comment: make an sql fiddle test db and post the link here to get more help